# western languages diacritics on wine

Tags: ubuntu, diacritics, wine

I am running a multilingual application in wine. The problem is
that a symbol appears in the place of characters with diacritics.
This happens with western languages, like portuguese and others.
However, I can see without trouble, characters of russian, chinese
and japanese languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it was an old version in the repositories. The version I'm running now works fine.